# Why react native render my state but return me empty when I want to use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api

Here my problem. I want to fetch an API, and I want to concat the new data on top of the old data. the data of my state render on the screen but whenever I want to use the data for concat or for some condition it is empty. I have tried to see my error but after some days I can't find it.

Here is all my states:

```
  const [K_OPTIONS, setK_OPTIONS] = useState([])
  const [selectedAlertes, setSelectedAlertes] = useState({})
  const [vintedItems, setVintedItems] = useState([])
  const [lastItem, setLastItem] = useState()
  const [cookie, setCookie] = useState()
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()
  const [isFirstSync, setIsFirstSync] = useState(true)
```

Here is my call to the API:

```
const fetchData = (params) => {
    fetch('here i have my url in my code')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      const lastItemTimestamp = lastItem 
   
      const items = data.items
      .sort((a, b) => b.photo.high_resolution.timestamp - a.photo.high_resolution.timestamp)
      .filter((item) => !lastItemTimestamp || item.photo.high_resolution.timestamp > lastItemTimestamp);


      if(items.length) {
        const newLastItemDate = items[0].photo.high_resolution.timestamp
        if(!lastItemTimestamp || newLastItemDate > lastItemTimestamp) {
         newLastItemDate.length ? setLastItem(newLastItemDate) : null
        }
 
       const itemsToSend = lastItemTimestamp && !isFirstSync ? items.reverse() : [items[0]];
         //here i tried to add the new data on top of the old but it only add the new data    since it say that vintedItems is empty. 
         setVintedItems(vintedItems.concat(itemsToSend)) 
      }
 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    setIsFirstSync(false)
  }
```

here is the set interval it trigger when I select a value in a list

```
useEffect(() => {
  let interval;
  if(Object.keys(selectedAlertes).length !== 0) {
    fetchData()
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, 10000)
  }
  return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
      setVintedItems([])
      setLastItem()
    }
}, [selectedAlertes])
```

```
style={styles.list}
          numColumns={2}
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingLeft:  15, paddingRight: 15, paddingBottom: 25 }}
          columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
          data={vintedItems}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          indicatorStyle="white"
```

if you need more explanation or more code ask me :)

Comment: A bit of a guess, but I *suspect* `fetchData` has a closure around `vintedItems` and isn't seeing updated values.  When you set the state to append the values, try this: `setVintedItems(vi => vi.concat(itemsToSend))`

Comment: @David i don't want to ask you to much but  I have the same problem with LastItem, it doesn't read the value, it return undefined but its not an array so I can't make it with your previous answer, do you have an idea ?